# How do i fix the error "Unhandled exception type Exception"

Tags: java, driver

The console is giving me the message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type Exception
```

```
package driver;

import exception.StackException;
import stack.*;

public class StackDriver 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        StackInterface<Painting> painting = new LinkedStack <Painting>();
        
        System.out.println("Creating five paintings.");
        Painting A = new Painting("Rembrandt" , "Netherlands" , "Dutch Golden Age");
        Painting B = new Painting("Leonardo da Vinci", "Italy" , "Renaissance");
        Painting C = new Painting("Michelangelo", "Italy" , "Renaissance");


        painting.push(A);
        painting.push(B);
        painting.push(C);
        
        try 
        {
//Below is the line that is giving me this error. Specially painting.peek();

            System.out.println("Peeking at top of painting stack." + painting.peek());
            
            
        }catch (StackException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
    }
}

// This is my exception package with the StackException class.

package exception;

public class StackException extends RuntimeException
{

    public StackException()
    {
        super("The stack is empty.");
    }
    public StackException(String msg) {
        super (msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try wrapping the whole main function in a try catch? Maybe creating the painting creates a stack exception? or pushing creates one?

Comment: According to the exception you get, your code ***does not compile***. How did you build it and how do you run it?

Comment: @PM77-1 should I post my "Painting" class?

Comment: Try changing the main declaration to `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception`

Comment: Changing the main declaration made it compile. Thank you!